Skip Proto file Binding classes generation if already present in AAR file or any other source
I have one AAR file added inside the libs directory in Android Studio project. I have added a proto compiler configurations inside the build.gradle file. I am trying to add a proto file inside the app module under src/main/proto directory. The AAR file contains the binding classes only for the same proto file added under the src/main/proto directory. The AAR file does not contain any proto files. After building a project I am getting error as
 R8: Type MyClassGrpcKt$PersistentLoggerCoroutineStub$disable$1 is defined multiple times:
How to configure the proto compiler inside the build.gradle file to skip the generation of binding classes which is already present or bypass this error
I tried unzipping the AAR file and access the classes.jar to look for the already generated bindings and skip proto binding generation.
I also tried to add configuration inside proto compiler to look for generated bindings inside the build/generated/src/proto.
The kotlin classes generated for proto are duplicated and also present inside the build/temp/kotlin-classes. I tried to delete those also to prevent duplicate classes error.

The simplest way is to remove or comment out the message definition for the class you don't want to generate from your .proto file.

I want to skip bindings or exceptions which are thrown as Error: defined multiple times during build process. It should not generate the binding if already present in any other source like AAR file classes.jar .
How to achieve this ?
